# Operations - Are the results of these two operations similar to each other?

Tags: math, numbers, calculation

Given two sets of numbers, i.e.,

`[3, 4, 5]` and `[7, 8, 9]`.

Are the results for `(3/7 + 4/8 + 5/9)` and `3 * (3 + 4 + 5) / (7 + 8 + 9)` *similar* to each other? Are there *any theorems* for this?

Comment: Which definition of similarity do you use?

Comment: The calculation results.

Comment: Well, `(3/7 + 4/8 + 5/9) = 187/126 ~ 1.48` and `3 * (3 + 4 + 5) / (7 + 8 + 9) = 3/2 = 1.5`. They are not equal; are they *close enough*? It depends on similarity definition you use.

Comment: Yeah, they are close enough for this example. What I want to know is that whether we can observe the similar phenomenon when the two sets of number are randomly selected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: If `d + e + f = 0`, but `d, e, f ≠ 0`, then the difference is **infinity**... mathematically speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's put the *reversed* question:

> Can difference between `a / d + b / e + c / f` and `3 * (a + b + c) /
>   (d + e + f)` be *arbitrary large*?

The answer is **positive**:

let `a = c = d = e = 1` and `b = f` is a *large number*. We have:

```
a / d + b / e + c / f = 1 / 1 + b / 1 + 1 / b ~ b + 1
3 * (1 + b + 1) / (1 + 1 + b) = 3
```

The difference is

```
b + 1 - 3 = b - 2
```

When `f = b` is arbitrary large, the difference (`b - 2`) is *arbitrary large* as well.

That's why the answer to the **original question** is

> there's no guarantee that the results will be similar, i.e. close
>   enough

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, it's clear and helpful！